# Lift is duplicating my content

Tags: html, scala, dom, lift

I'm learning the ins and outs of the Lift framework, wanting to make a simple webpage. I wanted to see how easy it was to apply a template to the page I was making, and decided to just apply the default one. To my surprise everything on the page got duplicated for no apparent reason. The page content is roughly based on the code from this talk: [ScalaDC (Scala + Lift + Angular) is Magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VH-S2UDN-NQ)

Here's what happened to my page:

[image: Duplicate stuff!]

And here's my code in question:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Which character is the best?</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body class="container">
  <div data-lift="surround?with=default&at=content">
      <h1>Which Character is the best?</h1>
      <button data-lift="CharacterSnippet.renderButton">Ask the server </button>
      <div id="char-div" style="display:none;" class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <p class="lead" >If only the server knew the answer...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <img width="512"/>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**default.html:** (pretty much unchanged from the one Lift comes with)

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title data-lift="Menu.title">App: </title>
  <style data-lift="CSS.blueprint"></style>
  <style data-lift="CSS.fancyType"></style>
  <script id="jquery" src="/classpath/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script id="json" src="/classpath/json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    .edit_error_class {
      display: block;
      color: red;
    }

    .sidebar ul {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
   }

   .sidebar ul li {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style:none;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     border-bottom:none;
   }

   .sidebar ul li a {
     display:block;
     padding:3px;
     text-indent:30px;
     text-decoration:none;
   }

   .sidebar ul li span {
     display:block;
     padding:3px;
     text-indent:30px;
     text-decoration:none;
   }

   .sidebar ul li a:hover {
     background-color: #eee;
   }

   .spinner {
     display:none;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 5px;
   }

   /* ]]> */
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column span-12 last" style="text-align: right">
      <h1 class="alt">Learning Lift<img class="spinner" alt="" id="ajax-loader" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"></h1>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="column span-6 colborder sidebar">
      <hr class="space" >

      <span data-lift="Menu.builder"></span>

      <div data-lift="Msgs?showAll=true"></div>
      <hr class="space">
    </div>

    <div class="column span-16 last">
      <div id="content">The main content will get bound here</div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="column span-23 last" style="text-align: center">
      <h4 class="alt">
        <a href="http://www.liftweb.net"><i>Lift</i></a>
        is Copyright 2007-2014 WorldWide Conferencing, LLC.
        Distributed under an Apache 2.0 License.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Removing `data-lift="surround?with=default&at=content"` from the first `div` in `body` makes the page load fine, which is weird since the template worked fine with the default code that was written in `index.html` when I started the project.

So what can I do to fix this duplication?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 parser that Lift uses causes this sometimes when it comes across invalid content.  In this case, I think the problem might be the way you are invoking the surround snippet.  When you've got multiple parameters to pass to a snippet, use `;` instead of `&` to delimit them.  So try:

```
data-lift="surround?with=default;at=content"
```

An unescaped `&` is used expected to start a character reference in HTML5.

Comment: It's weird, because the official documentation uses & between default and at

Comment: Did that fix it though?  It could be something else off in the markup, but that's the first thing that drew my eye.

Comment: It doesn't change anything actually. What I've found works, is to delete everything around the div that needs to be surrounded, because looking at the generated code you can see it basically just forced `default` in between `body` and `div`